# как добавить данные полученные в OnComplete в ArrayList

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, vkontakte-api

```
final ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

for ( VKApiDialog msg : list) {
    final String[] result = new String[1];
    final int id=msg.message.user_id;
    VKRequest request1 = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS,String.valueOf(msg.message.user_id),VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
    request1.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            user = ((VKList) response.parsedModel);
            result[0] =user.getById(id).toString();
        }

    });

    users.add(result[0]); 
}
```

после выхода из `onComplete` переменная становится `null`

если `users.add(result[0])` вызвать внутри, то при вызове извне `onComplete`  после выполнения `users.size()` получаю 0.

`

```
                    for ( VKApiDialog msg : list) {
                        final String[] result = new String[1];
                        final int id=msg.message.user_id;
                        VKRequest request1 = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS,String.valueOf(msg.message.user_id),VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
                        request1.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                                super.onComplete(response);
                                user= ((VKList) response.parsedModel);
                                result[0] =user.getById(id).toString();
                                users.add(result[0]);
                            }

                        });

                        System.out.println(users.size());`
```

Результат:

`04-12 13:50:00.792 11984-11984/com.example.belzik.messagefromvk I/System.out: 0
04-12 13:50:00.793 11984-11984/com.example.belzik.messagefromvk I/System.out: 0
04-12 13:50:00.793 11984-11984/com.example.belzik.messagefromvk I/System.out: 0
04-12 13:50:00.793 11984-11984/com.example.belzik.messagefromvk I/System.out: 0`

Comment: Вы под дебагом посмотрите, что первей выполняется users.add(result[0]); или result[0] =user.getById(id).toString(). Я думаю сразу проблему поймете

Comment: Скорее всего VKRequestListener отрабатывает асинхронно.  В строке  `users.add(result[0]); ` вы не можете рассчитывать на то, что `result[0]` уже будет содержать значение. Перенесите `users.add(result[0]);` в `onComplete()`.

Comment: Пробовал, извне onComplete вызывал после этого `users.getSize()` , получил 0

Comment: @kalugin1912, вы уверены, что вызывали `users.getSize()` **после** того, как отработал `VKRequestListener`?

Comment: да, посмотрите я добавил правку с `users.size()`

Comment: @kalugin1912, см. ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Если я все правильно понял, `VKRequestListener` отрабатывает асинхронно и вы хотите дождаться его выполнения для всех `msg`. Для этого вам нужно самостоятельно реализовать синхронизацию между основным потоком и асинхронными callback-ами. Можно воспользоваться [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Это работает так:

- Вы создаете что-то вроде счетчика с исходным значением равным количеству ожидаемых событий.
- Основной поток перед тем, как продолжить выполнение, ожидает, когда счетчик дойдет до нуля.
- В каждом асинхронном слушателе событий в случае успеха и в случае ошибки уменьшаем счетчик на единицу.

Выглядит это так:

```
final List<String> users = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(list.size()); // наш счетчик

for ( VKApiDialog msg : list) {
    final int id=msg.message.user_id;
    VKRequest request1 = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS,String.valueOf(msg.message.user_id),VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
    request1.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            user = ((VKList) response.parsedModel);
            users.add(user.getById(id).toString());

            latch.countDown(); // уменьшаем при успехе
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            latch.countDown(); // при неудаче тоже уменьшаем
        }
    });
}

latch.await(); // основной поток будет ждать здесь
// тут уже можно вызвать users.getSize()
```

Примеры применения `CountDownLatch` в Android есть в [официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: Все равно получаю 0

Comment: выведите `latch.getCount()`, он точно достиг ноля?

Comment: нет, `I/System.out: 10`

Comment: ArrayList не thread safe. Нужно (если нужно) использовать Collections.synchronizedList. И весь код должен выполняться в отдельном потоке иначе latch подвесит главный поток и будет ANR.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо, что заметили. Пофиксил.